# vector output in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have written a program that outputs the maximum and minimum number of days frost was recorded along with the corresponding year and month. I am reading this data from a file and inputting what i need into vectors.

In the file the months are displayed in integers 1-12, My question is that in my program when outputting the month, how can I output "January" when in the the file it's a 1?

Comment: Use an array of month names?  (Or vector.  Or map...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `std::array` of `std::string`. The index will correspond to the month name. Just make sure you account for 0-based indexing, e.g. "January" == `0`, not `1`.

```
std::array<std::string, 12> months = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

Then

```
cout << "The highest number of days frost was recorded is: " 
     << maxFrost 
     << ". The date was: " 
     << months[maxMonth - 1]   // adjust to 0-based index
     << ", " 
     << maxFyear 
     << ".\n" 
     <<endl; // maximum frost with month and year
```

Comment: If you prefix the month names with a dummy value, then the month numbers will line up with the month names.  Make the array 13 elements.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I have been able to fix it to work myself, thank you also!

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler doesn't support `std::array`, you can use a fixed array of characters:

```
static const char * month_names[] =
{
  "Dummy", // to make names line up with month numbers.
  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December",
};

int main(void)
{
  for (unsigned int m = 1; m <= 12; ++m)
  {
    cout << m << ") " << month_names[i] << endl;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

*Note:  The type `char *` is used for the array since `char *` can be stored as fixed data and accessed directly.  Using `std::string` would involve creating a `std::string` instance for each month name before accessing them.*